# Math in Redux-form. Adding Fields together

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm trying to add several sets of fields together in a redux-form using selectors.

Currently I'm doing it like this...

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    let total = (Number(this.props.tradeInTotal) + Number(this.props.thirdPartyEquipmentTotal));
    if(
      this.props.equipmentTotal != prevProps.equipmentTotal || 
      this.props.softwareTotal != prevProps.softwareTotal ||
      this.props.thirdPartyEquipmentTotal != prevProps.thirdPartyEquipmentTotal ||
      this.props.miscTotal != prevProps.miscTotal ||
      this.props.tradeInTotal != prevProps.tradeInTotal
    ){
      this.props.dispatch(change('mainForm', 'totalPurchase', total));
    }
  }
```

This isn't particularly repeatable, and is super hideous from a boilerplate perspective.

I also have a strange issue in that this doesn't start calculating until more than one of the subtotals has a number in it (this might be remedied by setting an initial value of 0, but that adds even more boilerplate) anyone have a better solution to adding fields in redux-form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the `props` are to do with calculating the `total`, you could use `Array.reduce`. For example:

```js
componentDidUpdate () {
  const total = Object.values(this.props)
    .reduce((total, value) => total + value, 0)

  if (/* new total differs from total in the store */) {
    this.props.dispatch(change('mainForm', 'totalPurchase', total));
  }
}
```

If there are additional props that need to be omitted, use `Object.entries` and `Array.filter` before summing up:

```js
componentDidUpdate () {
  const totalKeys = ['equipmentTotal', 'softwareTotal', ...]
  const total = Object.entries(this.props)
    .filter(([key, value]) => totalKeys.includes(key)) // filter out non-relevant props
    .reduce((total, [key, value]) => total + value, 0)

  if (/* new total differs from total in the store */) {
    this.props.dispatch(change('mainForm', 'totalPurchase', total));
  }
}
```

Comment: meaning all of the props called in the selector? I unfortunately have multiple sets of fields that are being added to create subtotals, and then the subtotals are being added to create totals.

Comment: In that case filter by key beforehand - I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: so this reduces the code a bit... which is great.  Do you have any ideas on cutting down the /* new total differs from total in the store */ section? Are you recommending saving total back to the store and then checking to see if its changed? As that would likely be even more boilerplate.

Comment: Sure, why can't you just check the actual `total` value in the store instead comparing stuff to `oldProps`? If there's a particular reason, you can apply the same `total` calculation code to `oldProps` as well and then compare the two.

Comment: Getting a ×TypeError: totalKeys.incudes is not a function

Comment: Also, are you thinking something along the lines of this... if (this.props.totalPurchase != prevProps.totalPurchase) {
    this.props.dispatch(change('mainForm', 'totalPurchase', total));
  }

Comment: Not sure why, Array.includes should be supported in all the major browsers. What browser are you getting the error in? Regarding the total comparison, sure, that is one of the options. After all you are only interested in if the total differs, not any specific part of it to dispatch the action.

Comment: Running Chrome 65.

Comment: Sorry, just now seeing there was a typo in my code. It's `Array.includes`, not `Array.incudes`. Good luck!

Comment: Awesome that fixed it. With regards to the update though. I don't think (this.props.totalPurchase != prevProps.totalPurchase)  will work... any other thoughts on how to watch for a change of any one of the key fields in order to fire the dispatch?

Comment: IE does not support Array.includes. So I still think you need to use alternative way to check for key's existence.