# Monitoring a variable for change and updating state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm currently trying to determine my options for monitoring a variable in React/Redux and using it to update state when it changes.

This pertains to another question I asked on here ([Math in Redux-form. Adding Fields together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49483710/math-in-redux-form-adding-fields-together/49483866?noredirect=1#comment85970944_49483866) incase you want context), but is specific to how to monitor and call the change event.

I use 3 pieces of state (mapped to props), and add them together like this...

```
let total = (this.props.sub1 + this.props.sub2 + this.props.sub3);
```

I then want to update my redux state for `total` everytime `total` changes...

Currently, I'm watching for changes to each piece of sub state and then updating total like this...

```
    if(this.props.sub1 != prevProps.sub1 || 
       this.props.sub2 != prevProps.sub2 ||
       this.props.sub3 != prevProps.sub3){ 
        this.props.dispatch(change('mainForm', 'total', total));}
```

This works, but it seems like there should be a way to just monitor the total vs each of the subs to set this state. Something like this...

```
if (this.props.total != prevProps.total){this.props.dispatch(change('mainForm', 'total', total));}
```

but that works :)

Thoughts?

Comment: Where are the props `sub1`, `sub2` and `sub3` coming from? Are they in the store as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React (and Redux) advocates having a single source of truth for all the application state. In this case, the `total` is just something that is built from the `sub`s. As such, it would make sense to not include it in the store (if the `sub`s are already in the store), and just compute it in the component itself.

This can be done in `mapStateToProps` in `connect`, or using a selector (like `reselect`).

```
connect(
  function(state, ownProps) {
    return {
      total: state.total.sub1 + state.total.sub2
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating `this.props.total` make sense when `total` rendered in different components with sub1, sub2, and sub3.
`total` can be calculated by the container.

Also, consider using Reselect (https://github.com/reactjs/reselect).